# Cambiar el icono del expandable list view android

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Quiero utilizar este icono con el anterior componente]

Quiero cambiar el icono de la primer imagen con el de la segunda imagen. como puedo hacerlo?

```
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:indicatorLeft="?android:drawableLeft"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684926/change-icon-of-expandable-list-view Creo que ese enlace te puede ayudar.

Comment: muchas gracias! me fue de ayuda tambien!! saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esto puedes usar el método [**setGroupIndicator()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setGroupIndicator(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)), donde asignas el `Drawable` que será usado como indicador.

Por ejemplo suponiendo tienes una imagen llamada "flecha" en tus recursos, obtienes el Drawable y lo asignas como icono a tu `ExpandableListView`:

```
Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.flecha );
expandableListView.setGroupIndicator(myIcon);
```

Comment: muchas gracias jorge!! me sirvio tu respuesta!! saludos.

Comment: Excelente jonatan, un saludo!